# How can we tell what the speaker wants to confirm in "Everyone thinks the show was great, {don't they/wasn't it}?"

Tags: tag-questions

I came across this question in my exercise book:

Everyone thinks the show was great, _______?

(A) don't they

(B) wasn't it

I think the answer depends on what the speaker wants to confirm. We can't really tell without further context.

However, I also think **wasn't it** may be wrong, because if the speaker wants to confirm that the show was great, he/she should have said **I think...** instead of **Everyone thinks...**

What do you think?

Comment: If the speaker wants to confirm that the show was great, he/she could leave out "everyone thinks" and just say: "The show was great, wasn't it?"

So, yes, you are correct in assuming "wasn't it" to be wrong.

Comment: Tags ask for confirmation of something - in this case confirmation that "everyone thinks the show was great, not that the show was great. Compare "Everyone thinks the show was great, don't they? ~ "The show was great, wasn't it?

Answer (score 2):

It has to be "don't they".

The tag question asks for confirmation, and you can ask for confirmation of the idea that "everyone thinks..."

In this example "think" means "believe".
What you think, or believe, has to be a statement.  *I think "the film was great"*  You don't think a question: *"I think is the film great". So you can't believe or think "the film was great, wasn't it".

So, the only possible answer is "don't they?"

If you wanted to confirm whether the show was great or not, you wouldn't start with "Everybody thinks..."

Answer (score 2):

In tag questions, the subject of the tag should match the subject of the sentence. The correct answer is "don't they" because the subject of the sentence is "everyone".

If the sentence was changed to:

> The show was great, ________?

then I would agree that the answer is "wasn't it", as "show" would then be the subject of the sentence.